# Missing information in the Ariadne GraphQL docs

Tags: python, flask, graphql, flask-sqlalchemy, ariadne-graphql

I'm trying to add authentication to a Flask-GraphQL API that I'm creating, and I'm using Ariadne to handle some of the GraphQL stuff.

The Ariadne docs (specifically page https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/mutations) defines the `resolve_login` and `resolve_logout` functions but references an `auth` variable with functions `login`, `logout`, and `authenticate` that don't seem to be referenced anywhere else in the docs (so I have no idea what to do with this). Could someone please shed some light on what's going here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs(https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/mutations), it is placeholder methods which needs to be implemented based on type of authenication required.

Comment: Please put a link to docs

Comment: https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/mutations